Dimension of $O(n)$ restricted to fixed rotation angle?
Take an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with even $n$ such that $\angle(x,Ax)=\pi/4$ for all $x$ with unit norm.
What is the dimension of the space of valid $A$?
We can generate $A$ by taking some $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix $U$ and using Jordan normal form as follows:
$$
A = U \left[ 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array} \right) 
\oplus \cdots \oplus 
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\end{array} \right) \right] U^T
$$
notebook

It appears to be at most $n(n-1)/2-n-1$ since diagonal entries are equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$ while offdiagonal entries squared add up to $1/(2n)$

Denote by $\mathcal M$ the set of those said matrices. Each fixed $A\in\mathcal M$ can be written as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}U\pmatrix{I_n&-I_n\\ I_n&I_n}U^T$ for some orthogonal matrix $U$. Hence the tangent plane of $\mathcal M$ at $A$ is given by
$$
\mathcal P=\{KA-AK:K^T=-K\}.
$$
Let $\mathcal K$ be the subspace of all skew-symmetric matrices in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and let $f:\mathcal K\to M_n(\mathbb R)$ be defined by $f(K)=KA-AK$. Then $\ker(f)$ consists of matrices of the form $U\pmatrix{X&-Y\\ Y&X}U^T$. Since $K$ is skew-symmetric, $X$ must be skew-symmetric and $Y$ must be symmetric. Therefore $\dim\ker(f)=\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2$ and
$$
\dim\mathcal M=\dim\mathcal P=\operatorname{rank}(f)=\dim\mathcal K-\dim\ker(f)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2=\frac{n(n-2)}{4}.
$$

Thanks , it's surprising that fixing (n/2) angles removes (n/2)^2 degrees of freedom
